# read file and see if number in lst are in numerical order

Tags: python

**the question asked to me:**

In the book All Creatures of Mythology, gnomes are kind, bearded creatures, while goblins tend to be bossy and simple-minded. The goblins like to harass the gnomes by making them line up in groups of three, ordered by the length of their beards. The gnomes, being of different physical heights, vary their arrangements to confuse the goblins. Therefore, the goblins must actually measure the beards in centimeters to see if everyone is lined up in order.
Your task is to write a function to assist the goblins in determining whether or not the gnomes are lined up properly, either from shortest to longest beard or from longest to shortest. The input will come from the file gnome.txt which starts with a line containing a single integer N, 0 < N < 30, which is the number of groups to process. Following this are N lines, each containing three distinct positive integers less than 100. For each group, a line saying "Ordered" or "Unordered" should be printed:
Usage:

> > > gnome()
> > >       Ordered
> > >       Unordered
> > >       Ordered

**The inside of gnome.txt**

3

40 62 77

88 62 77

91 33 18

**my code so far**

```
def gnome():
    infile = open('gnome.txt')
    firstline = infile.readline()
    for i in range (int(firstline)):
        gnomeList = infile.readline().split()
        intlist = []
        for str in gnomeList:
            intlist.append(int(str))
            if intlist[i] > intlist[i + 1]:
                print ('Unordered')

        else:
            print ('ordered')
```

**errors im getting**

File "C:/Users/cjakob/Desktop/homework6.py", line 34, in gnome
    if intlist[i] > intlist[i + 1]:
IndexError: list index out of range

**thank you all very much I have been working on this for hours**

Comment: What is this, homework cheat day? My guess is that you have a `list index out of range on line 34`

Comment: thank you, but this is not homework cheat day. This is self learning day. I would appreciate valuable feedback as I am self learning

Comment: The error already gave you valuable feedback - that your list index is out of range- ie. the index to the list (i+1) is greater than the number of values in your list. StackOverflow isn't supposed to be a crowd-sourced debugger and the enormous blurb about gnomes isn't really relevant to the programming issue and simply makes it appear that you're trying to get us to do your homework.

Comment: Matt thank you but I will use this resource as I see fit if you find issue with my question, please do not respond to it. Your grievance falls on deaf ears and only annoys. Regardless thank you for your post

Comment: The error message tells you the line on which the error occurs. The message, as @MattCoubrough noted, tells you what is wrong. You have a range call that is going to run through every case of `i` in the list. Think about what will happen when you get to the *last* one and try to access `intlist[i + 1]`: there will not be any more items in the list to access. You may find it helpful to use `print` to help you see what is going on in cases like this.

Comment: Chris thank you very much g. Myers thank you too

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing what your indices mean. Your index `i` represents the number of **sets** of three gnomes that you will need to process, not the number of gnomes in each set.

Since you are looking to check whether the most recently added value is greater than the one added two ago, you could just change your if statement to `if intlist[-2] > intlist[-1]:`. This negative index represents in Python the element n counting back from the end of the list.
Note though that then you will need to make sure you aren't doing this when there is only one element in the list or it will throw an exception because `intlist[-2]` will not exist!

Enjoy Python :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def gnome(gnome_list):
    return gnome_list == sorted(gnome_list) or gnome_list == sorted(gnome_list, reverse=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('gnome.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if gnome(line.split()):
                print('Ordered')
            else:
                print('Unordered')
```

This will compare the list to sorted versions (both ascending and descending) of itself and return the Boolean result.

Answer (score 0):

Other approach:

```
f = open('gnome.txt').readlines()[1:]
def check(a):
        if sorted(a) == a:
            return True
for x in f:
    x=x.split()
    if check(x) == True:
        print " ".join(x),"Ordered"
    else:print " ".join(x),"Unordered"
```

output:

```
40 62 77 Ordered
88 62 77 Unordered
91 33 18 Unordered
```

In the above code i have a `check` function that takes the list,if `list == sorted(list)`,it will return True, indicating Ordered.
For Big files dont use `readlines`

Comment: It's much more pythonic to check directly and return the boolean result `return a == sorted(a) or a == sorted(a, reverse=True)`. THe OP stated that the the function should print `Ordered` if the list was in ascending or descending order.